# No puedo validar el inicio sesion y que me lleve a index.html (PHP)

Tags: php, html, login, validación

Tengo un problema con este codigo de php. El objetivo es que luego de conectarme a la base de datos y presiona el boton "login" me lleve a otra pagina llamada "index.html" que ya esta hecha. Sin embargo al presionar con usuario y contraseña correctos me lleva nuevamente a action.php.

"neumaticos" es el nombre de la db.
"root" es el usuario de phpmyadmin.
"users" es el nombre de la tabla en la db.

Estoy utilizando xampp. Muchas gracias

¿Alguna ayuda?

```
<?php

session_start();

// Estas primeras 3 lineas es para evitar errores en la compilacion

ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 'Off');
error_reporting(0);

$username = $_POST['username']; //es el "name" que le asignamos a las variables en login.html
$password = $_POST['password'];

function connect(){
    if (!($db=mysql_connect("localhost","root"))){     // "root" nombre de usuario
        echo "Error conectando a la base de datos";
        exit();
    }
    if (!mysql_select_db("neumaticos",$db)){          // neumaticos es el nombre de la db
        echo "Error seleccionado la base de datos";
        exit();
    }
    return $db;
}

$conectarse = connect();

// Vamos a utilizar sql para comparar variables
// select todos desde login que es la tabla de usuarios
// username y password son el nombre de las columnas en la db

$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username ='".$username."' AND password ='".$password."' ";
$q = mysql_query($query, $conectarse);

try {

    if (mysql_result($q, 0)){              // Si se obtuvo un resultado entonces
        header("location:index.html");           // Abrir index.html
        die();
    }else 
        echo "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos";  
}catch(Exception $error){}
mysql_close($conectarse);

?>
```

Comment: Estas usando un driver que ya no es recomendable usar, puedes utilizar `mysqli`, depende de la versión de php que estes manejando

Comment: Exacto, además `mysql_connect` tiene serios problemas de vulnerabilidad, deberías cambiar todas esas funciones para la conexión. También puedes usar `PDO`

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!